# cross apply for function to calculate employees working hours

Tags: sql-server

How to calculate employee working hours based on the shift start and end is work day.It should be decimal(09:00 to 17:30) as 8.5 hours. Other examples of valid shift patterns are 08:00-16:00,09:00-17:00 and 08:00 - 20:00.No need to deduct any lunch breaks

I have tried the function but need to use cross apply?Any suggestions please

```
Create function[dbo.][WorkingHours]
(
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate `datetime,
@StartTime time,
@EndTime time
)

Returns Table
as
Return
(
select convert(varchar,sum(datediff(minute,A.startDatetime,A.EndDatetime))/60)+':'+
convert(varchar,sum(datediff(minute,A.startDatetime,A.EndDatetime))%60) as TotalWorkedHours
from
(
select[calenderdate]as Date,
             convert(datetime,[calenderdate])+''+@Starttime as                             StartDatetime,
          convert (datetime,[calenderdate])+''+@EndTime as                 EndDatetime

from [dbo].[Date] D
where WeekDay not in(1,7)
and D.CalenderDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and holiday = '0'

)A

)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It seems you have an inline table value function. But you also seem to have misplaced your question as there doesn't really seem to be one here.

Comment: Why do you need to use cross apply? Are you not getting accurate results? Please post sample data and expected output